# Why for-in loops can't have multiple variable declarations?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, syntax-error, for-in-loop

```js
let example = {
a:20,
b:40,
c:60
}

for(let j=0,i in example){
console.log(example[i]*j);
j++;
}
```

**Why normal for loop can have multiple variable declarations, but for-in loop cannot? Or am I doing this somehow wrong?**

Comment: The grammar allows only one declaration there, and that's pretty much that. The reasons are probably lost in history.

Comment: @Ufuk - I have updated my answer which includes official statements from MDN site regarding this scenario, please check it once

Comment: @abhijat_saxena I've seen the edit. Thank you for the great explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand the frustration, you're using the same keyword so why doesn't it behave similar? But I think you should think about it this way:
for is a way to define a loop, for as long as some condition is true, with different way for how to define that condition.

In a regular for loop, you loop as long as the middle part (the condition) is true:
`for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

This is similar to how a while loop might work, but it's a syntactic short cut:

```
let i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    i++;
}
```

So the for..in is a for loop that has another sort of condition, for every property in this object, so as long as you have more properties it will keep looping.
You could write that like this as well:

```
const keys = Object.keys(example);
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i];
    const value = example[key];
}
```

You also have for...of, which loops over items in a array, but that is syntactic sugar for:
`for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { const item = array[i]; }`

Also consider how a do...while loop is like a while loop but with some slightly different rules and behavior. Rather than getting frustrated with the syntax try to understand how it's saving you time by making your code a little less wordy, but in order to do that it needs to be a little different for each case. The alternative would be to have very many language keywords.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing a code that's not syntactically correct.

> in JavaScript you cannot use `for-in` expression with any other assignment expression.

You can simply pull out the `j=0` assignment out of the for loop and that should fix the error

```js
    let example = {
        a:20,
        b:40,
        c:60
    }
    
    
    let j=0
    for(i in example){
        console.log(example[i]*j);
        j++;
    }
```

[Edit] I have the found the following content in the official MDN site for the same scenario

 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

As per the site - it's  a publicly known issue that ChromeV8 and other browsers are trying to look into
[image]

For more info check the following references
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_for-in_initializer

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748550

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1164741

Comment: Because they create different sort of loops and thus need different syntax for the language to understand what to do, I wrote a longer answer showing some of this, hope that helps you!

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing your code to not declare any variables inside the parentheses of the for loop. I have never seen this done; maybe it's possible, but it would be simpler to declare a variable above the for loop, like this (assuming that's what you were hoping to do):

```js
let example = {
    a:20,
    b:40,
    c:60
}


let j=0
for(let i in example){
    console.log(example[i]*j);
    j++;
}
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments: "You should probably add a `let` before the `i` declaration, otherwise it's going to be globally defined." I've just changed that in the snippet!

Comment: You should probably add a `let` before the `i` declaration, otherwise it's going to be globally defined.